# Rails Query Filtering by Comparing if Two Date Ranges Overlap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, activerecord

I have 4 date params  `event_start, event_end, view_start, view_end`

How do I write  a Model.where() (or the appropriate active record query syntax) so that IF any date in-between `event_start` and `event_end` is the same as any date in-between `view_start` and `view_end` then that record is included?

`event_start` and `event_end` are columns in my table(properties on Model).

`view_start` and `view_end` are available in the params hash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are only two cases when the record is not to be displayed: when `view_start` is greater then `event_end` and when `view_end` is less then `event_start`. (assuming view dates are in correct order). Since we are looking for the negation of that, using DeMorgan's law:

```
if view_start < view_end
  Model.where('event_start < ? AND event_end > ?', view_end, view_start)
else
  Model.none
```

Comment: I like the logic you figured out. I have validation on the event_start and event_end so I can do with out the If Else statement right? Is this answer better then kardeiz answer? It is easier to read and understand for a rails/ruby beginner.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  Model.
    where(Model.arel_table[:event_start].lt(params[:view_end])).
    where(Model.arel_table[:event_end].gt(params[:view_start]))
```

which will find overlapping ranges. Depending on hour your application treats the endpoints, you may need to change these to e.g., `gteq`.

Comment: This seems to be working! I have to research how though. I would like it if date ends match that the record is included. Is this better then BroiSatse answer?

Comment: This will definitely match if the end dates for both are the same. What it won't match is if the start date of one is equal to the end date of the other; if you wanted this to match then you would need to add the "... or equal to" for one or both ends.

Comment: This is pretty much the same thing as @BroiSatse's answer. It just uses `Arel` to formulate the "greater/less than" logic. I prefer using Arel where possible, because it allows you to write queries that are completely RDBMS-agnostic (though that probably doesn't matter here).

Comment: I see, I understand whats going on now. I was going to give @BroiSatse the answer because I can understand how it works and its shorter syntax. But now I see and will leave it.